# Start Hostapd on Android over ADB Shell

Tags: android, adb, android-source

I am tyring to start hostapd over the adb shell on Android. I want to start hostapd with a custom `hostapd.conf` file to add *vendor specific elements*

```
interface=wlan0 
driver=nl80211 
ssid=meinessid 
channel=6 
hw_mode=g 
vendor_elements=dd500911223344
```

My Problem is, that i cant figure out how to start hostapd (with the custom hostapd.conf) correct over adb shell . 
My device is a Galaxy Nexus with Cyanogenmod 10.2 Nightly Build. 
I tried to start hostapd with

```
# hostapd -B /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf
```

but it didn't worked.

Comment: to begin with... use "regular" `/` slashes in your file path

Comment: that was a typo, sorry , in adb shell i used / of course ...

Comment: how exactly did it fail? did you get any error messages? have you tried to increase the verbosity with `-dd`?

Comment: when i do `# hostapd -v` i get the correct informations, so im pretty sure hostapd is working , but when i try to start it there is absolutly no output , not even an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS your device is galaxy nexus, this would be the steps:-

- turn off wifi in UI
- give permission to your `.conf` file-- `chmod 777 hostapd.conf`
- `ifconfig wlan0 up`
- kill any hostapd is running and then issue this comamnd:- `hostapd -e/data/misc/wifi/entropy.bin -BK /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf`

Conform in `ps` hostapd is running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !In ps is see this `wifi      1411  1     2428   360   c015ce2c 40285480 S hostapd
`  , so i think hostapd is running correctly , but i cant see a hotspot on wireshark etc. ? Is there another step to turn on the hotspot ?

Comment: search your ssid in any other device, if it turned on properly means you should see beacons in channel 6

Comment: i cant find the ssid from `hostapd.conf` on any device . Do you have any idea what i can try to run the hotspot / hostapd properly ? i think hostapd start right , because it creates its wlan0 file in /data/misc/wifi/hostapd and its entropy file , but the hotspot doesnt start ?

Comment: are you able to turn tethering/hotspot through device UI?

Comment: yes, i was able to activate the hotspot through UI and this method works fine for ICS , but not for Android 4.3 , the hostapd process is started , but there is no hotspot you can see on a client